# Bluetooth audio connection flutters

Tags: bluetooth

I have a rooted phone and I recently updated to Android 5.1.1.

I have a bluetooth headset device, and since the upgrade, the connection has been distinctly degraded. The device pairs, connects, and plays sounds no problem. But, every 30 seconds or more, the sound flutters, as if the connection is weak. It makes listening to music basically pointless.

The difference before and after the upgrade is clear, so I'm sure it's the upgrade that did it.

The question is, is this fixable or adjustable? Or is it just a bad ROM and I need to find another?

Comment: Might be a buggy ROM (did you dirty flash?). Try forgetting the device and repairing, otherwise you might have to reflash the ROM.

Comment: @Huey, thanks for responding. What does the term "dirty flash" mean?